# How to use ssh-rsa public key to encrypt a text?

Tags: encryption, openssl

So, the scenario is: Given I'm Bob, I want to encrypt some message for Alice. The only public key I have is her `ssh-rsa` id_rsa.pub like this:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAyb+qaZLwgC7KAQJzYikf3XtOWuhlMXVv2mbTKa5dp0sHPRd2RaYnH8ZRkt7V8bjqct1IHGCuxI8xyoEp4at3FHe6j9RfWiarc1ldLUCmTtryI0GGpRs6Zpvqdtpcq/1NCIYtUQAvsImyEFCtqmB2suDo1ZSllZQ0x9TCKHdCANYIOeaniuFzR57POgE3vxk/r6PO24oy8BIWqxvi29r0n1LUigVBJ7CmMHuzb4/+i1v6PxV1Lqnj6osPP9GpXpsh8kLUCby/KcmcryWNdSP0esyCdDxkA5hlIuk8qL1vzsyPluUQuc0BEHu6nuw8WQlCF1mFFxcpJL+MhWEr01WIIw== sikachu@Sikachus-Notebook.local

So, is there a way to encrypt a string using this public key so she can use her private key from `id_rsa` (generated from `ssh-keygen`) to decrypt the message?

(I know that it's possible right away if you're using `.pem` key pair file. If you can show me how to convert this to the format that `openssl` supports, that'd be great as well!)

Thanks!

Comment: You and alice should really investigate gpg ... http://www.gnupg.org/ ;D

Comment: Hahaha, indeed! However, the scenario that I have here is that I have access to their `ssh-rsa` public key already, and I don't want to add another layer of complexity (like, asking the recipient to go install gpg, etc.)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It's possible to convert your ssh public key to PEM format(that 'openssl rsautl' can read it):

Example:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -m PKCS8 > id_rsa.pem.pub
```

Assuming 'myMessage.txt' is your message which should be public-key encrypted.

Then just encrypt your message with openssl rsautl and your converted PEM public-key as you would normally do:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey id_rsa.pem.pub -ssl -in myMessage.txt -out myEncryptedMessage.txt
```

The result is your encrypted message in 'myEncryptedMessage.txt'

To test your work to decrypt the with Alice' private key:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa -in myEncryptedMessage.txt -out myDecryptedMessage.txt
```

Comment: I wrapped this up in a script that pulls the users public key from GitHub. https://github.com/twe4ked/catacomb

Comment: This does not work for me.  My `ssh-keygen` does not have a `-m` option.  (I cannot figure out how to ask ssh-keygen for its version.)  Replacing `-m` with `-t` works, but then `openssl` tells me "unable to load Public Key".  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285294/how-do-i-fix-openssl-unable-to-load-public-key.

Comment: Same issue as Jason has on MaxOS Mavericks.  Replaced -m with -t for keygen enabled key generation.

Comment: Note that this only works if the file is small enough. e.g. 200 bytes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143514/how-to-encrypt-a-large-file-in-openssl-using-public-key

Comment: Echoing what @hyh said, this works only if the input file is small (the line is somewhere around 254 bytes, otherwise It will give "rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_SSLv23:data too large for key size:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.20.2/src/crypto/rsa/rsa_ssl.c:73" error.

Comment: Can it also work for signing messages and for ecdsa and ed25519?

Comment: Building on the script from @twe4ked, I made a bash script that does what this post describes with some nice command line parameters and a readme: https://git.e.tern.al/s2/sshencdec

Comment: On macOS, this doesn't do anything but output the following: `Usage: rsautl [options]` followed by the available flags. My version is `LibreSSL 2.8.3`. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Seems to be the `-ssl` option that is causing the issue. When I remove it, it works.

Comment: It would be great if you also explains the params passed.

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to [ssh-vault](https://ssh-vault.com/) it uses ssh-rsa public keys to encrypt "create a vault" and the ssh-rsa private key to decrypt "view content of the vault"

Comment: This seems to do a lot more than what the OP asked for, which is nice (looks like a well engineered tool!) but a bit misleading as it took me quite a few minutes to find out that this is not a wrapper around what is described in the accepted answer but something else on top of that. Leaving this as a note for everyone who is only looking for the barest solution to the problem, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.bjornjohansen.com/encrypt-file-using-ssh-key. The idea is to generate a single-use symmetric key that is short enough to be encrypted using SSH public key. Then, you use the symmetric key to enrypt your text, and send both the encrypted text and the encrypted key to the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

NecroThreading a bit, but I had the same issue and catacomb did not quite cover it, so I ended up making my own variation. Also, I found that dealing with file redirects a bit confusing for my end-users, and the need to download the script beforehand a bit tedious, so my version wraps itself to make an auto-extractible file so the end-user has the easiest time getting the file.

It can be found at https://github.com/BaptisteRichard/rsaCrypt

Please advise that my users are on gitlab and not github so I tweaked that a bit, but it could easily be retrofitted. MR are welcome

Answer (score -3):

Why not do this the super obvious way that doesn't require rolling your own crypto.

Alice sftps to alice@bobserver.com which is setup to only allow public key authentication for the account alice.  The properties of ssh nicely ensure that only alice can authemticate.  Even a man in the middle attack fails since (assuming you disable ssh1 and insist on the right settings) the initial communication using DH creates a value known to both alice and bob but not to any man in the middle and this can be used to authenticate that no reply or MITM attack can see the contents of the communicatino.

So have alice sftp into your box and download the file.

Comment: How is using openssl rolling your own crypto?

Comment: As an example, using RSA to encrypt a 1024 character string would fail because of message size. To overcome this problem the implementer is in a precarious situation, especially if the messages are repeated.

It is safer to use RSA to encrypt a new symmetric cipher key and initialization vector which would be unlikely to repeat, so so generate unique cipher text for ever message sent, and gain the symmetric cipher speed, and reduce the amount of cipher and plain text to attack the RSA key with.

Hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: This method requires Bob to trust Alice, or to lock down bobserver.com so that Alice can't do anything malicious.

Comment: Its rolling your own in the sense that alice has to go throw a considerable amount of unusual operations to decrypt not in the sense of the underlying math being roll your own.  As this was asked in terms of command line utilities rather than an API or theoretical perspective assumed the individual actually wanted to transfer some concrete information not piggyback a new protocol on top of ssh.  As such practically sftp seemed far easier and yes it does require either looking down the server, trusting Alice or wiping the server afterward.

Comment: Seems to me that in the above one is actually vulnerable to someone intercepting the email in which you explain to alice exactly how she can decrypt this unusual message and giving her a sequence of commands that instead safely decrypt Charlie's MITM message (openssl commands are like magic incantations to most) while the server idea avoids all this in favor of standard commands many are familiar with and if bob runs it from the computer he is encrypting on he is trusting it anyway.  Obviously the best answer depends on the threat model but from q context this likely would serve them better.